# JSLint : Expected 'new' before

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am facing issue in calling ReturnData(); method in CreateOutput().

Here is the code.

```
function ReturnData() {
    "use strict";
    return "The data";
}


function CreateOutput() {
    "use strict";
    var takeValue = ReturnData();
    bind(takeValue);
}
```

Error

> JSLint : Expected 'new' before 'ReturnData'.

Comment: It probably assumes that because your function name starts with an upper-case letter that it's intended to be used as a constructor function. Prevalent JavaScript coding style is to use lower-case for ordinary functions and upper-case for constructors.

Comment: jslint is telling you that it expected `new` before `returnData`. You could have found the answer by googling `jslint expected new before`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint is assuming that `ReturnData` is a constructor. You could rename it to `returnData` or turn the rule off. You can turn it off with `--newcap` on the commandline.

Comment: How to set the rule off?

Comment: @shankar.siva Depending on your version of JSLint, you may not be able to turn the rule off. The newest version, eg, the one currently at [JSLint.com](http://www.jslint.com), will give, `Bad option 'newcap'.` JSLint is serious about creating standardized code. That's a good thing. Code that passes JSLint is more likely to pass JSLint everywhere, which is much less likely when linting code through a heavily optioned JSHint or ESLint installation.

Comment: I am not able to find the --newcap. Can you able to tell me how can we do that, If possible?

Comment: @shankar.siva where/how are you running jslint?